# Add Row and Edit Function Does Not Work

Tags: javascript, html

Here, I've inserted the HTML and JavaScript codes for the Add/Edit/Delete/Save function for the respective table as shown in the snippet.

I encountered some errors on the JavaScript codes when I tend to move the `Save` button below the table. In addition, I have also inserted the radio buttons in the `Save` and `Edit` function.

I am unable to run the `Save` and `Edit` functions after the modifications and I would appreciate a guidance in solving this.

```js
function edit_row(no) 
{
  var editBtn = document.getElementById("edit_button" + no);
  var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save_button" + no);
  editBtn ? editBtn.style.display = "none" : '';
  saveBtn ? saveBtn.style.display = "block" : '';

  var name = document.getElementById("name_row" + no);
  var value = document.getElementById("qty" + no);
  var yes = document.getElementById("yes" + no);
  var noEle = document.getElementById("no" + no);

  var name_data = name && name.innerHTML;
  var value_data = value && value.innerHTML;
  var value_yes = yes && yes.innerHTML;
  var value_no = noEle && noEle.innerHTML;

  name.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='name_text" + no + "' value='" + name_data + "'>";
  value ? value.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='value_text" + no + "' value='" + value_data + "'>" : '';
  yes ? yes.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='yes_radio" + no + "' value='" + value_yes + "'>" : '';
  noEle ? noEle.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='no_radio" + no + "' value='" + value_no + "'>" : '';
}

function save_row(no) 
{
  var nameEle = document.getElementById("name_text" + no);
  var name_val = nameEle && nameEle.value;
  var valueEle = document.getElementById("value_text" + no);
  var value_val = valueEle && valueEle.value;
  var yesEle = document.getElementById("yes_radio" + no);
  var noEle = document.getElementById("no_radio" + no);
  var qtyEle = document.getElementById("qty" + no);
  var yes_val = yesEle && yesEle.value;
  var no_val = noEle && noELe.value;

  document.getElementById("name_row" + no).innerHTML = name_val;
  qtyEle ? qtyEle.innerHTML = value_val : '';
  yesEle ? yesEle.innerHTML = yes_val : '';
  noEle ? noEle.innerHTML = no_val : '';

  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";
}

function delete_row(no) 
{
  document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
}

function add_row() {
  var new_name = document.getElementById("new_name").value;
  var new_value = document.getElementById("new_value").value;
  var new_yes = document.getElementById("new_yes").value;
  var new_no = document.getElementById("new_no").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var table_len =  (document.querySelectorAll('.data_row').length) + 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(len).outerHTML = "<tr class='data_row' id='row" + table_len + "'><td id='name_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_name + "</td><td id='qty" + table_len + "'>" + new_value + "</td><td><input type='radio' id='yes" + table_len + "'>" + new_yes + "</td><td><input type='radio' id='no" + table_len + "'>" + new_no + "</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'><input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></td></tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_value").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_yes").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_no").value = "";
}

function add_row2()
{
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name2").value;
 var new_value=document.getElementById("new_value2").value;
 
 var table=document.getElementById("data_table2");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td><td id='value_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_value+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_name2").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_value2").value="";
}

function add_row3()
{
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name3").value;
 var new_value=document.getElementById("new_value3").value;
 
 var table=document.getElementById("data_table3");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td><td id='value_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_value+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_name3").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_value3").value="";
}

function add_row4()
{
 var new_name=document.getElementById("new_name4").value;
 var new_value=document.getElementById("new_value4").value;
 
 var table=document.getElementById("data_table4");
 var table_len=(table.rows.length)-1;
 var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML="<tr id='row"+table_len+"'><td id='name_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_name+"</td><td id='value_row"+table_len+"'>"+new_value+"</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button"+table_len+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' id='save_button"+table_len+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+table_len+")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+table_len+")'></td></tr>";

 document.getElementById("new_name4").value="";
 document.getElementById("new_value4").value="";
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <form id="radioForm" method="get" align="center">
    <table style="width:80% table-layout:fixed" align="center">

      <!--Attributes of table. Colspan used to insert sub-title for the main title.-->
      <h3 align="center">
        <B>Initial (On Arrival)</B>
      </h3>
      <table class="table1" style="width:70%" align="center" id="data_table" cellspacing=2 cellspacing=5>
        <tr>
          <th>Test Points</th>
          <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
          <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
          <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="data_row" id="row1">
          <label id="group1"> <!--label is used to control the respective group of radio buttons-->
    <td id="name_row1">Initial (On Arrival)</td>
 <!--The input box in the 'Value' column is set as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="20" align="center" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <!--The check boxes of 'Yes' and 'No' is created as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes" id="yes('1')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="No" id="no('1')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>


        <tr class="data_row" id="row2">
          <label id="group2">
    <td id="name_row2">Drop Test (Portable Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes" id="yes('2')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No" id="no('2')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('2')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>

        <tr class="data_row" id="row3">
          <label id="group3">
    <td id="name_row3">Power Up Test (Mobile Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes" id="yes('3')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No" id="no('3')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button3" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('3')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('3')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>

        <tr class="data_row" id="row4">
          <label id="group4">
    <td id="name_row4">User Interface Room</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty4" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes" id="yes('4')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="No" id="no('4')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button4" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('4')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('4')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="text" id="new_value"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" id="new_yes"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" id="new_no"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" id="savebtn1" value="Save">
      <br><br>
```

Comment: What errors? What doesn't work?

Comment: The errors I see seem clear enough - `'1'` and `1` are not the same, and there are no items with the id `yes` or `no`.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for your feedback. I've updated the question with the errors stated. I am unable to run my Save and Edit functions.

Comment: @KenY-N Hi there. Thank you for the feedback. I have updated my codes. So sorry that I might have overlooked at the codes as I'm just using Notepad as my developing tool.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are using Notepad to edit - view the console in your browser when you test, or here you can see errors displayed up front when you press the `Run code snippet` button. BTW, it is still giving errors here.

Comment: @KenY-N Thank you once again. Yes, that is the issue here. I am unable to define from where the error is coming from. I really need help on this.

Comment: On Chrome, you press `Ctrl+Shift+I` to get to Developer Tools, and then when you get an error, the console will display a stack trace where you can click to go to the various callers.

Comment: @KenY-N Yes, I seem to have identify the error and also corrected it ald. But I still need the functions to work. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't use comments so I decided to share my little research about your code in an answer.

I copied your code and run in my browser, browser gave me an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null
   at edit_row (New Text Document.html:4)
   at HTMLInputElement.onclick (New Text Document.html:87)
```

which points to this statement:

```
document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "block";
```

It seems your html does not have an element whose id is `save_button1`, I just only see an element have id `savebtn1`.

BTW, you could detect errors on your own, just open your html file in your browser, and right click, select "Inspect" or any other stuff. This will open a console which you can see what's happening on your webpage.

Updated:
After running your edited version of code, the first row is doing good. But the second row and other throw an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
at edit_row (New Text Document.html?qty=20&qty=60&qty=60&qty=60:12)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (New Text Document.html?qty=20&qty=60&qty=60&qty=60:86)
```

It is about ID again, your radio element did not have ids.

Update: I see a lot of errors because of elements have no a valid ID, ensure elements you used have proper ID will help.

Update: Well... Let's check your edit function carefully

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null
```

for statement

```
var yes = document.getElementById("yes" + no);
```

Here, browser will search element whose id is `yes1`, but in your html, it does not exist. It does have radio `yes('1')` but that's not identical to what browser want. Change radio IDs from `yes('1')` to `yes1` in html will help.(Or change javascript code from `"yes" + no` to `"yes('" + no "')"` also fine)
Do this to "no" radios.

After doing this, no errors were thrown while clicking edit button.

Next, the row added missing two radio inputs.
Actually this function is doing great. But a small typo ruins this.

```
<td input="" type="radio" id="yes_row6">on</td>
```

This is what function inserted. You could clearly seen what's wrong about it.

The first and second cells are empty because of you did not add input elements in your code. But its ID seems correct. Also I am wondering why initial row have no cells contains id like `value_rowX`(X is a number), is it a mistake?

Edit and Delete button are not on the same row. The reason they moved is you missed a ` tag before edit button's code. Another typo.

Update: Here is my version of code, which is working:

```js
function edit_row(no) {
  var editBtn = document.getElementById("edit_button" + no);
  var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save_button" + no);
  editBtn ? editBtn.style.display = "none" : '';
  saveBtn ? saveBtn.style.display = "block" : '';

  var name = document.getElementById("name_row" + no);
  var value = document.getElementById("qty" + no);
  var yes = document.getElementById("yes" + no);
  var noEle = document.getElementById("no" + no);

  var name_data = name && name.innerHTML;
  var value_data = value && value.innerHTML;
  var value_yes = yes && yes.innerHTML;
  var value_no = noEle && noEle.innerHTML;

  name.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='name_text" + no + "' value='" + name_data + "'>";
  value ? value.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='value_text" + no + "' value='" + value_data + "'>" : '';
  yes ? yes.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='yes_radio" + no + "' value='" + value_yes + "'>" : '';
  noEle ? noEle.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='no_radio" + no + "' value='" + value_no + "'>" : '';
}

function save_row(no) {
  var nameEle = document.getElementById("name_text" + no);
  var name_val = nameEle && nameEle.value;
  var valueEle = document.getElementById("value_text" + no);
  var value_val = valueEle && valueEle.value;
  var yesEle = document.getElementById("yes_radio" + no);
  var noEle = document.getElementById("no_radio" + no);
  var qtyEle = document.getElementById("qty" + no);
  var yes_val = yesEle && yesEle.value;
  var no_val = noEle && noELe.value;

  document.getElementById("name_row" + no).innerHTML = name_val;
  qtyEle ? qtyEle.innerHTML = value_val : '';
  yesEle ? yesEle.innerHTML = yes_val : '';
  noEle ? noEle.innerHTML = no_val : '';

  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";
}

function delete_row(no) {
  document.getElementById("row" + no).outerHTML = "";
}

function add_row() {
  var new_name = document.getElementById("new_name").value;
  var new_value = document.getElementById("new_value").value;
  var new_yes = document.getElementById("new_yes").value;
  var new_no = document.getElementById("new_no").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var table_len = (document.querySelectorAll('.data_row').length) + 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(len).outerHTML = '<tr class="data_row" id="row' + table_len + '">' +
    '<td id="name_row' + table_len + '">' + new_name + '</td>' +
    '<td id="qty' + table_len + '">' + new_value + '</td>' +
    '<td><input type="radio" id="yes"' + table_len + '">' + new_yes + '</td>' +
    '<td><input type="radio" id="no"' + table_len + '">' + new_no + '</td>' +
    '<td><input type="button" id="edit_button' + table_len + '" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row(' + table_len + ')"> <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row(' + table_len + ')"></td>' +
    "</tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_value").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_yes").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_no").value = "";
}

function add_row2() {
  var new_name = document.getElementById("new_name2").value;
  var new_value = document.getElementById("new_value2").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table2");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'><td id='name_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_name + "</td><td id='value_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_value + "</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len + "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></td></tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_name2").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_value2").value = "";
}

function add_row3() {
  var new_name = document.getElementById("new_name3").value;
  var new_value = document.getElementById("new_value3").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table3");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'><td id='name_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_name + "</td><td id='value_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_value + "</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len + "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></td></tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_name3").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_value3").value = "";
}

function add_row4() {
  var new_name = document.getElementById("new_name4").value;
  var new_value = document.getElementById("new_value4").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table4");
  var table_len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(table_len).outerHTML = "<tr id='row" + table_len + "'><td id='name_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_name + "</td><td id='value_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_value + "</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len + "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></td></tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_name4").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_value4").value = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <form id="radioForm" method="get" align="center">
    <table style="width:80% table-layout:fixed" align="center">

      <!--Attributes of table. Colspan used to insert sub-title for the main title.-->
      <h3 align="center">
        <B>Initial (On Arrival)</B>
      </h3>
      <table class="table1" style="width:70%" align="center" id="data_table" cellspacing=2 cellspacing=5>
        <tr>
          <th>Test Points</th>
          <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
          <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
          <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="data_row" id="row1">
          <label id="group1"> <!--label is used to control the respective group of radio buttons-->
    <td id="name_row1">Initial (On Arrival)</td>
 <!--The input box in the 'Value' column is set as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="20" align="center" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <!--The check boxes of 'Yes' and 'No' is created as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes" id="yes('1')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="No" id="no('1')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>


        <tr class="data_row" id="row2">
          <label id="group2">
    <td id="name_row2">Drop Test (Portable Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes" id="yes('2')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No" id="no('2')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('2')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>

        <tr class="data_row" id="row3">
          <label id="group3">
    <td id="name_row3">Power Up Test (Mobile Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes" id="yes('3')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No" id="no('3')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button3" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('3')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('3')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>

        <tr class="data_row" id="row4">
          <label id="group4">
    <td id="name_row4">User Interface Room</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty4" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes" id="yes('4')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="No" id="no('4')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button4" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('4')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('4')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="text" id="new_value"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" id="new_yes"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" id="new_no"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" id="savebtn1" value="Save">
      <br><br>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. I have edited the codes in the snippet and also removed the `save_row` function as it is no longer need in use. Thanks a lot for the tips, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Advice you might be getting up votes because we can consider this as an answer but don't get into the habit be very selective till you get your comment privilege.

Comment: @cerberus99 You're welcome. I have update the error I found in answer. Check it out.

Comment: @Sand Sure. I know advice should use comments. But I can't :(. I will be careful about this and I will think twice about when I should post an answer or a comment.

Comment: Once your get the comment privilege it's all ok but till then be very very selective because lot of down votes will make you unable to post. SO is a grate tool when used wisely. Think of this as MMO game your character get's better when it get upgrades to get upgrades you need points to get point you need to play fair, SO same kind of principle.

Comment: @Sand Understood. Your advice helps me a lot. Thanks. :)

Comment: @CodeingBoy Thanks a bunch for the feedback again. I've edited and still encountering the errors. :(

Comment: @cerberus99 Updated. Check it out and fix your problems.

Comment: @CodeingBoy I have updated my snippet, smh I cannot seem to find the input of `on` in the codes.

Comment: @cerberus99 no you are still not fixing that typo. In function `add_row`, search `<td input type='radio' id='yes"` in your template html. Modify it to `<td><input type='radio' id='yes"`. Another typo is contained in no radio, fix it.

Comment: @CodeingBoy Yes, I am getting the same output, but i am unsure why the `on` val is at the radio button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154743/discussion-between-cerberus99-and-codeingboy).

Answer (score 1):

You need some checks for whether it exists, I just modify a example:

```js
function edit_row(no) {
  var editBtn = document.getElementById("edit_button" + no);
  var saveBtn = document.getElementById("save_button" + no);
  editBtn ? editBtn.style.display = "none" : '';
  saveBtn ? saveBtn.style.display = "block" : '';

  var name = document.getElementById("name_row" + no);
  var value = document.getElementById("qty" + no);
  var yes = document.getElementById("yes" + no);
  var noEle = document.getElementById("no" + no);

  var name_data = name && name.innerHTML;
  var value_data = value && value.innerHTML;
  var value_yes = yes && yes.innerHTML;
  var value_no = noEle && noEle.innerHTML;

  name.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='name_text" + no + "' value='" + name_data + "'>";
  value ? value.innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='value_text" + no + "' value='" + value_data + "'>" : '';
  yes ? yes.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='yes_radio" + no + "' value='" + value_yes + "'>" : '';
  noEle ? noEle.innerHTML = "<input type='radio' id='no_radio" + no + "' value='" + value_no + "'>" : '';
}

function save_row(no) {
  var nameEle = document.getElementById("name_text" + no);
  var name_val = nameEle && nameEle.value;
  var valueEle = document.getElementById("value_text" + no);
  var value_val = valueEle && valueEle.value;
  var yesEle = document.getElementById("yes_radio" + no);
  var noEle = document.getElementById("no_radio" + no);
  var qtyEle = document.getElementById("qty" + no);
  var yes_val = yesEle && yesEle.value;
  var no_val = noEle && noELe.value;

  document.getElementById("name_row" + no).innerHTML = name_val;
  qtyEle ? qtyEle.innerHTML = value_val : '';
  yesEle ? yesEle.innerHTML = yes_val : '';
  noEle ? noEle.innerHTML = no_val : '';

  document.getElementById("edit_button" + no).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("save_button" + no).style.display = "none";
}

function delete_row(no) {
  document.getElementById("row" + no + "").outerHTML = "";
}

function add_row() {
  var new_name = document.getElementById("new_name").value;
  var new_value = document.getElementById("new_value").value;
  var yes = document.getElementById("yes").value;
  var no = document.getElementById("no").value;

  var table = document.getElementById("data_table");
  var len = (table.rows.length) - 1;
  var table_len =  (document.querySelectorAll('.data_row').length) + 1;
  var row = table.insertRow(len).outerHTML = "<tr class='data_row' id='row" + table_len + "'><td id='name_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_name + "</td><td id='value_row" + table_len + "'>" + new_value + "</td><td><input type='button' id='edit_button" + table_len + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' id='save_button" + table_len + "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + table_len + ")'> <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + table_len + ")'></td></tr>";

  document.getElementById("new_name").value = "";
  document.getElementById("new_value").value = "";
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <form id="radioForm" method="get" align="center">
    <table style="width:80% table-layout:fixed" align="center">

      <!--Attributes of table. Colspan used to insert sub-title for the main title.-->
      <h3 align="center">
        <B>Initial (On Arrival)</B>
      </h3>
      <table class="table1" style="width:70%" align="center" id="data_table" cellspacing=2 cellspacing=5>
        <tr>
          <th>Test Points</th>
          <th colspan="4">Cycle-Time</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td class="cent"><b>Value</b></td>
          <td class="cent"><b>Yes</b></td>
          <td class="cent"><b>No</b></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr class="data_row" id="row1">
          <label id="group1"> <!--label is used to control the respective group of radio buttons-->
    <td id="name_row1">Initial (On Arrival)</td>
 <!--The input box in the 'Value' column is set as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="20" align="center" name="qty" id="qty1" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <!--The check boxes of 'Yes' and 'No' is created as below-->
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="Yes" id="yes('1')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group1" value="No" id="no('1')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button1" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('1')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('1')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>


        <tr class="data_row" id="row2">
          <label id="group2">
    <td id="name_row2">Drop Test (Portable Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty2" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="Yes" id="yes('2')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group2" value="No" id="no('2')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button2" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('2')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('2')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>

        <tr class="data_row" id="row3">
          <label id="group3">
    <td id="name_row3">Power Up Test (Mobile Only)</td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty3" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="Yes" id="yes('3')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group3" value="No" id="no('3')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button3" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('3')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('3')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>

        <tr class="data_row" id="row4">
          <label id="group4">
    <td id="name_row4">User Interface Room</td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="number" value="60" align="center" name="qty" id="qty4" maxlength="4" size="4"/></td>
 <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="Yes" id="yes('4')"></td>
    <td class="cent"><input type="radio" name="group4" value="No" id="no('4')"></td>
 <td>
  <input type="button" id="edit_button4" value="Edit" class="edit" onclick="edit_row('4')">
  
  <input type="button" value="Delete" class="delete" onclick="delete_row('4')">
 </td>
  </label>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="text" id="new_value"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" id="yes" name="group28" value="Yes"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="radio" id="no" name="group28" value="No"></td>
          <td class="cent"><input type="button" class="add" onclick="add_row();" value="Add Row"></td>
        </tr>

      </table>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" id="savebtn1" value="Save">
      <br><br>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback. Smh, the edit function does not work :(

Comment: I modify it to work, but you haven't add the save button so, the save won't work for this original row, but for the new row it will be OK.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. The `Edit` and `Add Row` functions works well. But I do not seem to see the `Yes` and `No` radio buttons in the `Add Row` function :(

Comment: Because you didn't add to the new row in `add_row` function: `var row = table.insertRow(len).outerHTML = "...";`There isn't the `Yes` and `No` radio.